# "sqlsrv_fetch_array" solo regresa un registro de base de datos SQl server usando PHP

Tags: php, sql-server

estoy haciendo uso de la libreria "sqlsrv" para interactuar con una base de datos SQLSERVER usando PHP, el problema es que al hacer un "SELECT *" solo me trae un solo registro, aunque en la tabla tengo 24 registros, mi codigo es el siguiente:

archivo de conexion

```
class Conexion{
    public function conect() {
        $serverName = 'MARMOTECH-LAB\DBMTECH';
        $connectionInfo = array("Database"=>"encuesta",
                                "UID"=>"usr_encuesta",
                                "PWD"=>"Si22500192319.",
                                "CharacterSet"=>"UTF-8");
        $conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);

        if ($conn) {
            echo 'CONEXION EXITOSA';
            return $conn;
        } else {
            echo 'FALLO EN LA CONEXION';
            die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
        }
    }
}
```

codigo inicia la accion

```
<?php 
    include "modelos/url.php";

    $preguntas = ControladorEncuesta::ctrControladorPreguntas();
    var_dump($preguntas);
```

este es el controlador:

```
<?php

class ControladorEncuesta{
    static public function ctrControladorPreguntas() {
        $tabla = "preguntas";

        $respuesta = ModeloEncuesta::mdlMostrarPreguntas($tabla);

        return $respuesta;

    }
}
```

este es el MODELO:

```
<?php

require_once "connection_sys.php";
class ModeloEncuesta {

    static public function mdlMostrarPreguntas($tabla) {
        $my_query = "SELECT * FROM $tabla";
        $conectame = Conexion::conect();

        $result = sqlsrv_query($conectame, $my_query);

        if( sqlsrv_fetch( $result ) === false ) {
            return die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
        }
        while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $result, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
            return $row;
        }
        sqlsrv_close($conectame);
        $conectame = null;
    }
}
```

el "var_dump()" me muestra:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero en mi base datos tengo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

note me trae siempre el segundo registro, si sirve de algo el usuario que uso para conectarme a la base de datos le di permisos de "db_accessadmin", las tablas las crea asi: 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

aunque el select lo estoy usando sin especificar ""db_accessadmin".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que el `return` te corta la ejecucion de la funcion.  Puedes crear un array y devolverlo fuera del `while` algo asi:

```
<?php

require_once "connection_sys.php";
class ModeloEncuesta {

    static public function mdlMostrarPreguntas($tabla) {
        $my_query = "SELECT * FROM $tabla";
        $conectame = Conexion::conect();

        $result = sqlsrv_query($conectame, $my_query);
        $results = array();

        try {
          while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $result, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
            $results[] = $row;
          }
        } catch(Exception $e) {
            return die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
        }
        sqlsrv_close($conectame);
        $conectame = null;

        return $results;
    }
}
```

Comment: "Denle una cerveza a ese caballero"....Gracias bro me sacaste de una.

Comment: *El problema es que el result te corta la ejecucion de la funcion.*  ¿No será más bien el `return` el que corta la ejecución, saliendo del `while` a la primera iteracción? Es un error que veo mucho por aquí, gente que usa `return` y escribe código más para abajo. Aquí es distinto, pero lo que hay que entender que cuando aparece un `return` el código retorna al llamador y no vuelve, a no ser que se vuelva a llamar esa función o método.

Comment: Tienes razon, fue un typo que ya corregi.  Gracias.